# How can I efficiently pass information from class tXmlDoc to class tXmlShape

Tags: c++

Following task:
I have an xml file with data that I need to process. This data is grouped in various nodes which are organized in an hierarchical way. For simplicity I reduce the structure of my xml file a bit:

```
<doc_root>
   <case_def>
      <shape number="1">
          ... shape data ...
      </shape number>
      <shape number="2">
          ... shape data ...
      </shape number>
   </case_def>
   <parameters>
   </parameters>
</doc_root>
```

This file is stored in a specific path with a specific name. My intention is to later pass this via argc parameter to main() but that is another issue. For the moment I am fine with having this information hard-coded.

Now I have a class `tXmlDoc` that has a method to load the entire xml document in a member variable `xml_doc` that serves as a handle to extract data of each nodes. My class `tXmlDoc` will also extract the entire `<doc_root>` node which itself can be used as a handle to access nodes `case_def` and `parameters` and in the end each `shape` node.

Here's the header file for the `tXmlDoc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include "../../libs/pugixml-1.11/src/pugixml.hpp"
#include "XmlData_General.h"
#include "XmlNodes.h"

namespace nXml
{
    //------------------------------------------------------
    class tXmlDoc
    {
    public:
        tXmlDoc();
        ~tXmlDoc();

        void LoadXmlFile(const std::string& file_name, std::string& file_path);

        pugi::xml_node GetRootNode();

        std::string GetFileName();
        std::string GetFilePath();
        std::string GetFullPath(const std::string& file_name, std::string& file_path); //returns string containing the full path directly to the file

        void SetFileName(const std::string& file_name);
        void SetFilePath(const std::string& file_path);

        bool GetFileLoaded();
        int GetErrorCode();

        pugi::xml_parse_result GetXmlResult();

        void LoadData();

    protected:
        std::string file_path = ""; //is set when calling LoadXmlFile
        std::string file_name = ""; //is set when calling LoadXmlFile

        bool file_loaded = false; //provides information is file was successfully loaded (file correctly loaded: true). Modified by method LoadXmlFile

        int error_code = 0; //provides information about occuring errors (no error: 0). Modified by method LoadXmlFile

        pugi::xml_parse_result xml_result; //contains information about parsing result. Filled by method LoadXmlFile

        pugi::xml_node root_node; //contains the root node of the xml document. Filled when calling LoadData (via calling GetRootNode inside LoadData)  

        pugi::xml_document xml_doc; //contains the entire document
    }
    ;

};
```

Now in order to access and process data in the `shape` nodes I've created a class `tShapeNode`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <charconv> 
#include "../../libs/pugixml-1.11/src/pugixml.hpp"
#include "XmlNodes.h"
#include "tXmlDoc.h"

namespace nXml
{
    class tXmlShape
    {
    public:
        tXmlShape();
        tXmlShape(const int shape_id);
        ~tXmlShape();

        pugi::xml_node GetShapeNode(const int);

        int GetShapeId();
        int GetAttributNumber();

        std::string GetShapeType(const int shape_id);
        std::string GetDescription(const int shape_id);

        void LoadData();

    protected:
        tXmlDoc xml_doc;

        pugi::xml_node shape_node;

        int shape_id = 0;
        int n_attr = 0;

        std::string description;
        std::string shape_type;
    }
    ;

}
;
```

As you can see I have added a `tXmlDoc` member to my `tXmlShapeNode` so that I can access data from `tXmlDoc` that I need for `tXmlShapeNode`. In order to access data stored in the `<shape>` node I need the handle for the `doc_root` node. So the idea was to use the constructor of `tXmlShapeNode` to load the data in the local `tXmlDoc xml_doc` member of `tShapeNode`. However, I then would have to do this for every shape inside my xml file and this seems to be not efficient in terms of memory and operations.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. How can I pass the information stored inside `tXmlDoc.root_node` to `tXmlShapeNode` withoud having to process the xml doc for each shape I have?
2. Is there a way to avoid global variables for passing information of file name and file path to tXmlDoc class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer part 1.

Instead of the shape classes xml_doc being a tXmlDoc object, you can make it a an object that **refers**  to the actual tXmlDoc object

using a C++ reference

```cpp
// note the '&' 
tXmlDoc & xml_doc;
```

or a pointer

```cpp
// note the '*'
tXmlDoc * xml_doc;
```

Either option can be used to get access to some remote object like the document class. Typically you will pass the reference to the doc class to your shape class in the constructor.

Here the constructor uses a reference:

```cpp
class tXmlShape
{
public:
  // tXmlShape(); //Now your constructor must include a reference, so this won't work
   tXmlShape(const int id,tXmlDoc & doc) : xml_doc(doc),shape_id(id){}
//...
   tXmlDoc & xml_doc;
   int shape_id;
};
```

Here using a pointer:

```cpp
class tXmlShape
{
public:
   // for clarity init the members in the constructor
   tXmlShape(): xml_doc(nullptr),shape_id(0){}
   tXmlShape(const int id,tXmlDoc * doc) : xml_doc(doc),shape_id(id){}
//...
   tXmlDoc * xml_doc;
   int shape_id;
};
```

References are not without their problems of course mainly to do with making sure that the object they are referring to actually exists. This is a major aspect of C++ and it is too complicated to cover in this one post, but you will find much literature about how to handle references

Comment: So do I understand correctly that in my ```tShapeNode``` class I define the member ```tXmlDoc& xml_doc```? How do I now pass the information to this reference? How does this reference know to which instance I am referring?

Comment: I added some info on how the arguments can be passed in the tXmlShape constructor. A reference can be initialised simply by initialising from the object it refers to  {int x; int& ref_to_x = x;} For functions the type of the function argument will select whether an object is passed by reference or by copying etc